# Teradara: Casting Seconds to Hours, Minutes and Seconds

Tags: sql, teradata

I need to cast a Duration, measured in seconds, Decimal(18,0) to Hours, Minutes and Seconds.

```
e.g.: 
8192 Seconds => 2:16:32 (Hours:Minutes:Seconds)
```

I've found ([here](http://forums.teradata.com/forum/database/converting-number-of-seconds-to-minutes-and-seconds)) that I can do this if the seconds are a literal string, like this:

```
SELECT CAST(INTERVAL '8192' SECOND AS INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND)
```

But when I try:

```
SELECT Event_Id
     , CAST(INTERVAL Duration SECOND AS INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND)
  FROM EVENT_TABLE
 WHERE <some conditions>
```

> Event_Id and Duration are both declared Decimal(18,0) in the table EVENT_TABLE

Teradata complains:

> **[Error 3707]** Syntax error, expected something like a string or Unicode character literal between the 'INTERVAL' keyword and the integer 8

What is the correct syntax or approach to use here?

---

**SOLUTION:** based on BellevueBob's post

```
SELECT Event_Id
     , CAST(
            Duration SECOND * INTERVAL '0000:01' MINUTE TO SECOND  /* 1 */
            AS INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND                             /* 2 */
           )
  FROM EVENT_TABLE
 WHERE <some conditions>
```

**Explanation:**

1. Multiply the known duration in seconds with an interval of one second length
2. convert the resulting intervall of seconds into an interval of hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: what about `select INTERVAL '8192' SECOND` (that would be ANSI SQL)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: that might be ANSI, but does it work with a column reference instead of the literal string '8192'? (that __was__ the question...)

Comment: what about:  `select duration_col_in_seconds * interval '1' second from foo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the same solution you found, try this:

```
select CAST(duration * INTERVAL '0000:01' MINUTE TO SECOND 
            AS INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND)
from (
   select cast(8192 as decimal(18,0)) as duration
   ) x
```

Comment: thanks... please review my edit to the original question to see if my explanation is correct.